# Failing to boot while trying to install Ubuntu 64-bit

Tags: system-installation

I am having trouble to get the problem resolved and have followed all the suggestions for similar problems, but no luck yet and nothing that matches my exact problem.

I am new to Ubuntu and this will be my first install on this system.

The following error keeps coming up no matter what I try.

[image]

My system

- CPU AMD FX8350
- Mobo Asrock FX950 Fitility professional
- GPU Radeon MSI R9295x Lightning edition
- RAM 16GB 2100MHz down clocked to 1800MHz
- HDD Kingston 520GB SSD, Western Digital 1TB, Seagate 500GB

Have Windows 10 running on the 1TB which has 2 500GB partitions. I want to install Ubuntu on my 520GB SSD.

Comment: Will the system boot in recovery mode? If so, enable networking, open a shell and run "sudo apt update && sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall".

Comment: This is on a new system install so not sure if there is away to get into safe mode still and how to do this, can you please clarify?  Thank you.

Comment: Hold shift while booting, then the grub menu should appear. There should be an entry similar to "advanced options for Ubuntu", so select that and find the option that says "recovery mode" in its name. Select that and you'll boot into recovery mode, after lots of white text on a black background you'll hopefully get to the options and you can enable networking and then you can drop to a root shell prompt. You'll need an Ethernet connection to run the command, or be able to control WiFi from the shell.

Comment: You may have 2 or more problems. Is this a desktop machine? Try booting the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB with the `nomodeset` parameter. Also, one of your SATA disks seems to have a problem. Disconnect all but the primary disk. See if Ubuntu installs now. Ping me at `@heynnema` with results.

Comment: Good day, thanks for the replay guys heynnema it was the other hhd all along still not sure how and wich 1 exactly but when i removed them ubuntu installed with no problems and plugged them back in and it seems to work so far.  Will keep you guys posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact solution to the "ata1,2,3,4,5,6,7 depending on the device id" is to unplug all sata HHD"do not need to remove SSD's or USB drives" and plug them in 1 by 1 till you get the same problem, this way you will identify witch drive it is, hopefully you have more than 1 :( .

I am still not 100% sure what causes it exactly and you to to fix the drive but in my case it was only crashing when I tried to do a ubuntu system install.

I hope this helps!

Good luck.